# Accepting username or email during sign in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a requirement to allow users to sign in with either an email or a username they have created during registration.

The following code snippet is my user journey step that references the underlying technical profile. The referenced `ContentDefinition` is utilising the `unifiedssp:1.1.0` data model.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SA-LocalAccount-SignIn" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

And the referenced technical profile that performs a validation check on the sign in identifier and password:

```xml
  <TechnicalProfile Id="SA-LocalAccount-SignIn">
            <DisplayName>Local Account Sign In</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" 
  Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">LocalAccountSignUp</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="LoginToAzureAD-OIDC" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

I know `setting.operatingMode` defines if the required sign in identifier is `Username` or `Email`. Is there a third option to allow both?

Specifying one enforces regex on the sign in identifier field and prevents the other from being used i.e. email addresses aren't accepted as input if `setting.operatingMode` is set to `Username`.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of the input error? I don't experience that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by regex patterns included in my email address and username `ClaimType` in the `ClaimsSchema`. Removing the regex attached to the username claim resulted in email addresses being accepted as valid input and I am now able to login using either a username or email address.